# Android Database sqlight

Tags: android, sql, database

The code I posted below is what I used for my Database in the android application. My program is currently still on my computer and running with the emulator. My question is how will this whole database thing work ones someone downloads my program off of google play? Will they have their own DATABASE_NAME and DATABASE_TABLE one their phone? In which case I wont have to worry about anything. Or will the DATABASE_NAME and DATABASE_TABLE need to be different for every used that downloads the program and uses the Database on the app? In this case I'm not sure how I would taylor the Database for each individual user. Any help is appreciated. Thanks...

```
public class DBAdapter {

private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter"; //used for logging   database version changes

// Field Names:
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_DE = "de";
public static final String KEY_MO = "mo";


public static final String[] ALL_KEYS = new String[] {KEY_ROWID,       KEY_DESTINATION, KEY_MONTH};


// DataBase info:
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Prog.db";
public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "prog_table";
//IF ANY CHANGES ARE DONE HERE THE VERSION NEEDS TO BE INCREMENTED OTHERWISE THE PROGRAM WILL CRASH
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1; // The version number must be incremented each time a change to DB structure occurs.

//SQL statement to create database
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_SQL =
        "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "  + KEY_DE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_MO + " TEXT " ");";

private final Context context;
private DatabaseHelper myDBHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;


public DBAdapter(Context ctx) {
    this.context = ctx;
    //initializing the DatabaseHelper
    myDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

// Open the database connection.
public DBAdapter open() {
    db = myDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

// Close the database connection.
public void close() {
    myDBHelper.close();
}

// Add a new set of values to be inserted into the database.
public long insertData(String de, String mo) {
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_DE, de);
    initialValues.put(KEY_MO, mo);


    // Insert the data into the database.
    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}



// Delete a row from the database, by rowId (primary key)
public boolean deleteRow(long rowId) {
    String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
    return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, where, null) != 0;
}

public void deleteAll() {
    Cursor c = getAllRows();
    long rowId = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_ROWID);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            deleteRow(c.getLong((int) rowId));
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    c.close();
}

// Return all data in the database.
public Cursor getAllRows() {
    String where = null;
    Cursor c =  db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, where, null,      null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}

// Get a specific row (by rowId)
public Cursor getRow(long rowId) {
    String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
    Cursor c =  db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, where, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase _db) {
        _db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_SQL);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase _db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading application's database from version " + oldVersion
                + " to " + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data!");

        // Destroy old database:
        _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);

        // Recreate new database:
        onCreate(_db);
    }
}




}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will they have their own DATABASE_NAME and DATABASE_TABLE one their phone?

-YES

> Will the DATABASE_NAME and DATABASE_TABLE need to be different for every used that downloads the program and uses the Database on the app?

-NO

When your app is installed to a handset, it will create its own database accordingly to your configuration. You have nothing to worry about the configuration itself. It will work well as your emulator did.

Tip:
You can actually use a mobile handset as your emulator. Your developing environment should detect it when you plugged it in with an adopter to your computer. E.g. Eclipse

Comment: Valid answer, but I would suggest that you refrain from referring to Eclipse as IDE for a new developer. Eclipse is no longer the supported IDE for Android and bugs are arising already.

Comment: Awesome! That is what I was hoping for. Thanks a lot Dexter. BTW I use Android Studio, though I don't like it that much.

Comment: One more thing. So each user will have their own storage? And is that storage on their phone or in a Database off their phone? How much storage do they actually have?

Comment: Thanks for the additional insight @JDenais

Comment: @NikBabinchuk- The storage is on their handset, thus the amount of storage capacity depends on the device.

Answer (score 0):

sqlite database

```
class Mydatabase(
    var page: Context,
) : SQLiteOpenHelper(page, "stor.db", null, 1) {

    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase?) {
        var mytable =
            "Create Table Userdata (Id integer primary key autoincrement, NAME text, EMAIL text, NUMBER text,PASSWORD text,BIRTH text)"
        db!!.execSQL(mytable)

        var usersave =
            "Create Table Usersave (Id integer primary key autoincrement, NAME text, NUMBER text,Userid integer)"

        db.execSQL(usersave)
    }


    override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase?, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {

    }


    fun InsertData(
        name: String,
        email: String,
        number: String,
        pass: String,
        birth: String
    ): Boolean {

        var sighup = "select * from Userdata where EMAIL = '$email' or NUMBER = '$number'"
        var cursor1: Cursor = readableDatabase.rawQuery(sighup, null)

        if (cursor1.count > 0) {

            Toast.makeText(page, "USER ALrready Exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            return false
        } else {

            Toast.makeText(page, "SuccessFully Register", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            var instantdatatable =
                "insert into Userdata (NAME , EMAIL , NUMBER ,PASSWORD ,BIRTH ) values('$name', '$email' ,'$number', '$pass' ,'$birth')"
            writableDatabase.execSQL(instantdatatable)

            return true
        }

    }

    fun logincheak(loginemail: String, loginpass: String): Cursor {

        var login =
            "select * from Userdata where (EMAIL = '$loginemail' or NUMBER = '$loginemail') and PASSWORD = '$loginpass'"
        var cursor: Cursor = readableDatabase.rawQuery(login, null)

        return cursor

    }

    fun InsertDataContectSave(edname: String, ednumber: String, userid: Int) {

        var readdata = "select * from Usersave where NAME = '$edname' or NUMBER = '$ednumber'"
        var cursor2: Cursor = readableDatabase.rawQuery(readdata, null)

        if (cursor2.count > 0) {
            Toast.makeText(page, "Already Save Number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(page, "Save Number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            var ContectSave =
                "insert into Usersave (NAME,NUMBER,Userid) values ('$edname','$ednumber','$userid')"
            writableDatabase.execSQL(ContectSave)
        }
    }

    fun ViewrMyconatct(userid: Int): Cursor {
        var ss = "select * From Usersave where Userid = '$userid'"
        var cursor = readableDatabase.rawQuery(ss, null);
        return cursor
    }

    fun deletecontact(id: Int) {

        var delet = " delete From Usersave where Id = '$id'"
        writableDatabase.execSQL(delet)

    }

    fun UpdateDataContectSave(edname: String, ednumber: String, userid: Int) {
        var update = "update Usersave set NAME = '$edname', NUMBER = '$ednumber' where Id = '$userid'"
        writableDatabase.execSQL(update)

    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Answers that contain only code are generally considered as poor answers on SO. What's more, you posted Kotlin code when the question is tagged "java" and contains only Java code. And your code is poorly formatted. I suggest that you learn how to use [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).